World views : why is religion an easily accepted premise while Quantum Mechanics is hard to swallow?
Preamble:
the question is on World Views by people who are in a position to formulate such. It implies a choice between rationalism/reductionism versus holism/spiritualism, and the comfort/discomfort associated with such choice. If deemed inappropriate or opinionated, then it will undergo this site's editorial sanctioning without resistance.
An argument could be made that people who take ghosts, demons and other supernatural phenomena as real, and adapt their behavior to it, believe as they do irrationally. Similar to a compulsive gambler who presumes that (fair) dice have a memory and a conscience while he ruins his finances. While everyone is free to hold whatever beliefs, the community requests rational behaviour from its members. Yet a large portion of educated people hold the belief that there must be something out-there that registers and guides humans to a goal with a purpose.
The fact that humans live in families, and parents fulfill a role of monitor and guide towards their children, might have conditioned us to view the world in such setting. But that is not an excuse to abandon the reductionist method for building a world view. Somehow the supernatural looks like being very easy to accept for many people.
Compare this to the strange and alienating effect that the basics of Quantum Theory have on students that learn it. The 'why' and 'how' questions suddenly take precedence over the 'how much' question that should be asked instead. Why is it much harder to accept that a particle can pass through both slits and interfere than that souls live on after death? Or that a statistical nature underlies QM and not a purposeful one? Hard to grasp, hard to swallow. But real. Many physicist advise to not philosophize on the basis below QM until more experimental data and/or mathematical insights pop up. Take it as it is.
What could be modified in people's 'conditioning' (if there is such a thing) to make the second more easy and the first less seductive for future generations?

I'm not inclined to vote to close this question yet because you're a new contributor. But I do think you need to revise it, and I'm absolutely certain it will be closed if you don't. The issue is that the first paragraph is overtly insulting to a lot of people, and that's inappropriate in any question. Can you revise the question to a more civil, polite, and neutral tone?

Beste @WouterM. I have indeed voted to close this because it's unclear to me what you actually want to ask: How to make religion less "seductive" to people? How to clear their minds from their "conditioning"? What kind of question is that? (Note that I'm asking this as an atheist. I would very much like to see that the social influence of religious groups becomes less.) But would you like to hear some brainwashing techniques? -- That's not philosophy.

@mudskipper: my question of "what makes us accept some things easily and what makes other things hard to swallow" goes to our learning-unlearning capacity. I use religion as an example because it shows human's capability to adhere to diametrical opposite views simultaneously without discomfort. And it is philosophy to aim for clarity, isn't it? ("Brainwashing" has got a super pejorative connotation, but "cleansing my thinking" is a noble ambition to me). If on reading the edited question anyone considers it unfit or unthoughtful, then please cleanse the site of it.

"Clarity" is indeed the dominant metaphor in philosophy for what is desirable :) (It's also funny that when philosophers appeal to clarity, it often becomes very unclear what they mean by that. Examples can be found all thru history: Zhuangzi, Descartes, Wittgenstein.)

Most people don't even think about QM, so the question of whether they "swallow" it is moot. They also don't need to think about how their computers or cars work, they just accept that they do and get on with their lives.

"Cleansing" your own thinking may be a noble ambition, but cleansing the thinking of others to agree with you carries frightening implications.  Also, curious what you mean about holding diametrically opposed views...

@MichaelHall : about 'cleansing the thinking of others' : argumentation with peers and part of education is essentially that : to try to change their minds. About 'diametrically opposed views' : Natural Philosophy concerning the universe out there (separate from inter-human affairs) creates a 'World View' that can either be purposeful (created) or without (Anyone's) purpose (sui generis). The opposed aspect boils down to either admitting partial ignorance (we don't know yet) or acceptance of the Revelation (we know). Apologies for my being opinionated. I do care.

"part of education is essentially that : to try to change their minds." And I would argue that education should present the facts as they are, teach critical thinking skills, and respect that differing opinions will form as a result.

The challenge quantum mechanics has is that it is quite different from the mid-scale interactions humans live with a daily basis, and are both preprogrammed (by evolution) and trained (by experience as well as by introductory study) to expect. Understanding the extremely small or the extremely large (or the extremely fast) requires accepting that at those scales effects which are unnoticeable under what we consider "normal" conditions become significant, and sometimes dominant.
Most religious beliefs, since they initially arose from attempts to explain the world as we see it, do not face that challenge of requiring a paradigm shift. We can easily visualize gods as parent figures, again from both experience and innate social instincts. We can imagine them taking human-like actions and making human-like decisions, and we generally simplify that by assuming they have human-like attributes. "God created man in his own image; man courteously returned the favor."
So quantum is, inherently, harder to wrap our heads around. Its main justification is that it makes successful predictions and we have been unable to falsify it yet or come up with a better alternative. Nobody really likes the need for quantum mechanics, but the universe doesn't care what we like.

I like and dislike quantum mechanics at the same time...

Well, some parts of it are certainly fun. IBM had a nice single photon optical bench simulator that came with a series of puzzles that involved using half silvered mirrors and polarizers, along with fully reflecting mirrors and adjusting distances to get a photon to interact with itself to produce the desired output. I wish I knew where I put my link to the website... The concept of using destructive interference to change where a single photon goes stretches the brain in interesting directions

@Philomath, but only until someone observes you, right?

@MichaelHall: Ooh, I missed that completely; nice observation. Beautifully done, Philo!

That's why I spend so much time by myself: more possibilities. But then I do interfere with myself in surprising ways.

Here are some quotes from some notables.
So the last one exceeds all the others in wisdom?

If quantum mechanics hasn’t profoundly shocked you, you haven’t understood it yet
Niels Bohr


I think I can safely say that nobody understands quantum mechanics
Richard Feynman


I don't like it, and I'm sorry I ever had anything to do with it.
Erwin Schrödinger


Quantum theory, though still in its formative stages, has already demonstrated its power in explaining phenomena that were previously mysterious. However, its philosophical implications require thorough investigation to reconcile it with our classical intuitions about nature
Max Planck


The quantum theory provides us with a striking illustration of the fact that we can fully understand a connection though we can only speak of it in images and parables
Werner Heisenberg


Compare this to the strange and alienating effect that the basics of Quantum Theory have on students that learn it. The 'why' and 'how' questions suddenly take precedence over the 'how much' question that should be asked instead. Suddenly it's much harder to accept that particles can pass through both slits and interfere. Or the statistical nature underlying QM. Hard to grasp, hard to swallow. But real.
What could be modified in people's 'conditioning' to make the second more easy and the first less seductive for future generations?
Wouter M


To later added paragraph

...choice between rationalism/reductionism versus holism/spiritualism, and the comfort/discomfort associated with such choice

In the seventeenth century two of the biggest bulls of the time were slugging it out on the foundations of physics.
Here's a quote from one of them:

Nothing is moved naturally except through contact and motion, and so in physics, everything happens mechanically, that is, intelligibly...


It pleases others to return to occult qualities or to Scholastic faculties, but since those crude philosophers and physicians [see that] those [terms are] in bad repute, changing the name, they call them forces.

Just to be clear here — What's going on?

A certain Leibniz is critical of a a new fangled fashion...
...a fashion championed by a certain Issac Newton
The criticism: Newton believes in occult (ie spiritual) forces that act from a distance, which Leibniz considers unworthy of good science.

Who of the two was wrong?
Leibniz rejecting (a) action at a distance (b) absolute space-time,
was closer to Einstein's general relativity than Newton was.
So you are free to rest in your cock-sureness of the rightness of the mechanistic and the wrongness of the spiritualistic outlook.
But history shows that what is material and what is spiritual is not a subject of stable agreement across long periods of time.

The last quote is about people. The answer is: teach science early and often. Teach it everywhere, by explaining how a light switch works, or the plumbing in your house. Which means: know those things yourself.

The obvious answer is conditioning. From birth, humans are conditioned by a wide range of influences to think in certain ways. Those influences include the fact that everyday objects obey classical physics and that children are subjected to religious schooling, fairy tales, stories and films about ghosts etc. If you had grown up in a world in which macroscopic objects had quantum properties, and gods and ghosts were never mentioned, you would find the former natural and the latter bizarre.

If you grow up in a world where the people around you understand the technology they use every day, like electricity and plumbing, radio and statistics, boy, it would sure help. Children can't learn what no one teaches them, or even knows.

I believe the truth to that answer is digestability. Quantum mechanics does not possess easily comprehended subject matter and people are lazy, for lack of a better word. And while the examples you provided aren't entirely difficult to grasp, the immediate depth of the field and stigma that accompanies it, is usually threatening to people outside of that academic realm. Religion is the foundation on which society was built. People have a tendency to be loyal to the traditions from which they were spawned. Whether it's for better or worse is not really taken into consideration when a conversation about one's faith is brought into question. There are elements of religion that quantum mechanics can't explain in the same way that quantum mechanics explains things that religion couldn't approach. The world is comprised of all different perspectives which create an abstract whole. And that ultimately adds to the beauty of it's overall dynamic. My question in response to your question is, what makes you think that quantum computation isn't just an avenue for us to become closer to understanding God? The thing about God is, the deeper we dig? The deeper it gets. The higher we go? The higher it gets. Infinity provides us the opportunity to go as far as we want, in any direction we choose to follow. And what's proven or disproven is relative because there will always be more to find.
"Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic" - Arthur C Clarke

your interpretation looks similar to the hypothesis that below it all there is just mathematics, information and interactions in 2D that only look 3-dimentional to us. A holographic universe. But in that case, why would we have a special place in it? And would the 'God' entity you mention be sentient and purposeful? That it would be nice if so, that's not a ground for accepting that view.

Perhaps we should accept that in the present day, technology is "the foundation on which society was built"? Maybe, for children's own safety, we should teach them as much as we can about the human and technological world before going off to infinity and beyond? Leave that for later.

I can't completely disagree with you. But faith is an important aspect to existence. It's not even about whether God exists or not. Providing a foundation for someone to have something higher to look to during some of the tragic situations life can offer us? It can be a lifesaver in those instances. Check out some information regarding spiritual science. It may give you a better look at what my idea of God is. It's not what you imagine God would be but it does live at your core. We were all spawned from it.

Statistical nature doesn't really mean anything. Probability is just a tool we developed to be able to compute things when things are too complex to do other wise.
From a classical physics standpoint a dice is not random at all, but computing with sufficient precision where it will land used to be too hard.
Similarly, when we want to discuss behaviour of an ensemble of particles, each particle follows deterministic laws, but even three or four are too many to keep track of. Luckily, large ensemble over long enough times will follow statistical laws.
There isn't anything fundamental in a probabilistic description, probability is just the most precise form of hand waving details.

Religion presents a narrative that in its simplistic form holds that everyone is worthy of saving and something wise and wonderful is there for us when we need it. Even if you disagree with that story, or dispute its premises or reality, you still have to admit that it's a nice story.
Quantum mechanics presents a narrative (of a sort) that in its simplistic form holds that nothing is real or certain, not even our perceptions or ourselves. It leaves us in a universe which is monstrously large and immensely cold (except where it's immensely hot), with nothing that cares one whit for our tiny lives on this tiny temperate ball around a common and insignificant star. Even if you love quantum mechanics, nothing about that story is appealing.
Most people think in narratives, and they prefer narratives that they like, or at any rate narratives in which they can see themselves as some small sort of hero in their own lives. There are no heroes in the quantum mechanics story: no right or wrong, no good or bad, no guidance or direction whatsoever. For most people, religion can mean something in their lives, while quantum mechanics is at best an interesting curiosity and at worst annoying nerd babble. They may in fact think that quantum mechanics is fundamentally true, and still find it fundamentally useless for anything. But religion has uses (even if they are sometimes misuses).
If your neighbor gets sick or a flood hits your town, religion can help you decide what to do; what does quantum mechanics have to say about that?
I'll add, just so it's said, that the mistake most proselytizing atheists make when they they try to pull people away from religion is that they try to take away a good story and replace it with, you know… no story at all. Most people are distinctly uncomfortable living without a narrative in which they can place themselves, and everyone gets angry when you disrupt their inner narratives 'just because…'. When we create a better story than the one religion offers, people will gravitate to it. But we don't create better stories when all we do is sh*t-post on the old ones.

I really like the eloquence in your reply, and the way you focus on the role of humans in the relation of 'us-versus-the-world-around-us'. People at large in everyday life have a slightly different view of these matters than those (philosophers and physicists) that invest some effort in getting a good picture of reality. And people adhere to nice feel-good stories, sure, but should we all be content with that? QM isn't any help for understanding macroscopic phenomena, and certainly not in inter-human affairs.  That it makes us feel insignificant is a tad depressing, true.

@WouterM.: I don't see a point in asking someone to be content with something they are clearly discontent with. That just creates more discontentment. But I do think it's important to recognize the reality of situations and move forward conscientiously. Belief in a god (or in ghosts or spirits or such) isn't in itself a problem and doesn't in itself interfere with understanding physics or QM. We only find problems when people turn beliefs into battle lines. Let people have what makes them feel comfortable and safe, and they are much more likely to listen to what you want to say.

I wish I could focus this discussion better, maybe transport it to Chat? I utterly failed in separating two aspects : (1) an (attempt at) interpretation of the nature of physical reality (out there) and humanity's capacity and willingness to crawl towards it, or (2) their willingness to aim for full Revelation in one giant leap. Both full of unknowns.

The question is ill-formed.
Are we talking about The Supernatural vis-a-vis The Quantum Mechanical? Very few people have any problem accepting that there exist indivisible-and-countable (quantum) things and that there are some principles which describe their interactions (mechanics).
Are we talking about specific supernatural claims vis-a-vis specific quantum mechanical claims? Lots of deeply religious people have problems accepting/comprehending specific claims of specific religions - even their own religions.

"Somehow the supernatural looks like being very easy to accept for many people" - You are turning it upside-down. Things are easy to understand only for dummies. To prove that, try to find big and respected thinkers in the history of humanity who were consistent materialists (physicalists)?
People who can analyze their own life and the lives of other people very quickly see that, when it comes to human life as a whole, there are numerous controls and balances everywhere. While in a pure physical understanding, things would have to be random and evenly spread.
